# How to run script using SSH from remote computer and avoid its interruption if remote computer goes offline

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a remote Linux server and I use it to run some very long tasks using SSH. It works great, but, of course, if the connection dies for some reason, the task dies.

Specifically, I'm running something like this:

```
[myName@localStation]$ ssh john_doe@myRemoteServer
Password: *****
[john_doe@remoteServer]$ ./myVeryLongTask.script > myOutputLog.txt
```

Is there a way to tweak the SSH connection in such a way that, if the network connection fails, the task keeps running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read up on the screen command ([here's a quick google result](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acuy.html))

Screen allows you to leave a remote connection running and come back to it for reasons exactly as you describe.  It's also useful for running unattended jobs or keeping sessions open indefinitely.

'man screen' for more info

EDIT: Here's a better link to a HOWTO: [screen: Keep Your Processes Running Despite A Dropped Connection](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen)

Comment: +1 And a month or so back I didn't know [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) existed, but after playing with it for a little, seems a bit more usable than the venerable `screen`.

Answer (score 5):

`screen` is indeed great for that. Another couple of options are `at` and `nohup`:

- `at`

  > at,  - queue, examine or delete jobs
  >      for later execution

  You can either use `at`'s interactive shell to launch the commands or save them in a text file and pass that to at:

  ```
  $ cat foo
  ./myVeryLongTask.script > myOutputLog.txt 
  $ at now < foo
  ```
- `nohup`

  > nohup  - run a command immune to hangups, with output
  >      to a non-tty

  To launch a command do

  ```
  $nohup ./myVeryLongTask.script > myOutputLog.txt
  ```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, [dtach](http://dtach.sourceforge.net/) is another option. Summary of `detach` in the above link:

*dtach is a tiny program that emulates the detach feature of screen, allowing you to run a program in an environment that is protected from the controlling terminal and attach to it later.*

It's smaller in size compared to `screen`, and has much more functionalities than `at` or `nohup`.